# Integral of phasor

Tags: circuit-analysis, phasor

Say \$v(t) = V_m\cos(\omega t+\phi)=\Re[V_me^{j(\omega t +\phi)}] = \Re[Ve^{j\omega t}]\$,
where \$V_me^{j\phi} = V\$.

Integrating gives
\$\int\limits_0^t v(t)\,dt = \Re\int\limits_0^t Ve^{j\omega t}\,dt = \Re\frac{V}{j\omega} (e^{j\omega t}\color{red}{-1})\$.
But that \$\color{red}{-1}\$ shouldn't be there as the integral of phasor just scales the original phasor by \$\frac{1}{j\omega}\$. Where is my error?

Comment: Hint : 

cos(wt + phi) = (e^(j*(wt + phi) + e^(-j(wt + phi))/2

Comment: @Ben that cleverly gets rid of \$\color{red}{-1}\$ XD I also wd like to know why my method is wrong...

Comment: You should integrate the whole expression I posted

Comment: @Ben do I get \$ \int_0^t(e^{j*(\omega t + \phi)} + e^{-j(\omega t + \phi)})/2\,dt = \frac{1}{j\omega}(e^{j*(\omega t + \phi)} - e^{-j(\omega t + \phi)})\Bigg|_0^t =\frac{1}{2j\omega}(e^{j*(\omega t + \phi)} - e^{-j(\omega t + \phi)} - e^{j\phi} + e^{j\phi}) \$

Comment: On second thoughts, I don't really know why you want me do that or how to move ahead @Ben

Comment: What's the exponential expression for a sine?

Comment: Well, first you wrote that \$ v(t)=\mathcal{Re}[V_me^{j(\omega t +\phi)}] \$ then at the integral you completely ignored the \$ \mathcal{Re}[\cdot]\$ part. Also, I'm not sure that \$ \int \mathcal{Re}[f(t)]dt =  \mathcal{Re}[ \int f(t)dt] \$, it might work for phasors though.

Comment: Ah right, my mistake.. `Re` should be there while integrating too

Comment: I think `Re` and \$\int\$ can be interchanged as taking `real` part before or after doesn't care what the imaginary part is:  \$\int Re(f(t) + jg(t))\,dt  = \int f(t)\,dt = Re \int f(t) + jg(t)\,dt\$

Comment: @jDAQ updated the post. thank you for letting me know..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The operator, \$\frac{1}{j\omega}\$, in the frequency domain is equivalent to **indefinite** integration in the time domain.

Comment: It is found in the exponential form of a sine.

Comment: My point is, the OP is using definite integration, which is where the -1 comes from.

Comment: @Chu thank you so I must discard constants. But the voltage across  a capacitor or the current through an inductor depend on the initial conditions too. How does it make sense to leave out constants?

Comment: The 1/jw equivalent to integration assumes initial conditions are zero - a pre-requisite for transfer function analysis and, consequently, the s -> jw substitution to express function as a steady state frequency response (all transients ignored).

Comment: Oh I didn't know that. Does that mean using phasors always gives the \$0\$ average value for the current or voltage we're solving?  @Chu

Comment: Phasors are based on peak or rms values, not average values. Integration, in this respect, should be viewed as anti-differentiation. Differentiation is ‘s’ as an operator in Laplace; integration is 1/s.

Answer (score 0):

There should be no constants as the initial conditions should be 0 and the circuit analysis involved is for linear circuits, otherwise stored energy will add non-linearity.